# How to extract a List<Long> from a map Map<List<Long>,Map<Long,String>> mapForCaAndInv

Tags: dictionary, hashmap

I want to retrieve List from this map and assign it to a new variable  of List,any suggestions how can i proceed with this .

Comment: List<Long> notice = new ArrayList(mapForCaAndInv.keySet()); -- i am trying something like this

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in the question itself.

Comment: Its basically i have a map Map<List<Long>,Map<Long,String>> abc , now i only want this keyset to be extracted and get it stored in another list like List<Long> anj.